# Redirect all but some to new URL?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301, permanent

I am moving site and I want to do a 301 redirect on all but some of the URLs,

Like this:

`oldsite.com/*` -> `www.newsite.com`

`oldsite.com/specific/article/to/redirect` -> `www.newsite.com/fancy/blah`

So there are a few things I want to redirect to specific pages but all the rest should just goto root, how can this be done in .htaccess?

Comment: what webserver are you using?

Comment: on the new site - nginx, on the old - apache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to the `.htaccess` file in the root directory of your old site.

```
#place your specific redirects first 
Redirect 301 /specific/article/to/redirect http://www.newsite.com/fancy/blah

RewriteEngine on

#then your general redirect all to new site last
RewriteRule ^ http://www.newsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

There's RedirectMatch if you've got only one URL that needs to be exempted.

```
RedirectMatch permanent !/specific/article/to/redirect http://www.newsite.com
```

for multiple URLs, you'd probably be better off with mod_rewrite and an external [rewritemap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) that lists the urls to be exempted.